# Purpose of NULL at the end of array?

Tags: c

I found this code from [Fedora's Defensive Coding](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Security_Team/1/html/Defensive_Coding/chap-Defensive_Coding-C.html) manual. They have this code snippet:

```
static const char *const string_list[] = {
  "first",
  "second",
  "third",
  NULL
};
```

What's the point of putting NULL at the end of the array? Surely the size of the array will always be known since it's an array at global scope.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786888/null-pointer-as-marker-of-end-of-array?rq=1

Comment: It is called a *sentinel*. As an alternative to a numerical number of elements, it marks the end of the string array.

Comment: it is a marker saying: no more data. otherwise you would have to have a second variable to hold the number of items in the array.

Comment: @user4722176 Did you find an answer to your question? If so, you should consider marking the answer that best fit you as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This is a so called [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). It allows you to use whatever method of inbounds-checking that lends itself more to your current approach.

Aren't you already dereferencing? check for `NULL` then, should keeping track of index not be required. Are you counting? check the count variable then.

The most prevalent use of this is there in most programs you write: The argument vector (`char **argv`) passed to `main` always has a `NULL` as the last member, although technically the `int argc` would have sufficed.

Answer (score 2):

The number of elements *is* known

```
elems = sizeof(string_list) / sizeof(char*);
```

but it's cleaner (and works more generally) to test for the `NULL` value, since you will be handling the string pointer anyway.

Note too the title of your link: *"defensive"*. In a more general case, the array might not be full so relying on its size is unsafe - there may be uninitialised pointers.

Comment: Rather consider `sizeof string_list / sizeof *string_list;`

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to iterate through the list with a pointer without keeping track of the index:

```
for (const char * const * string = string_list; *string; string++)
    do_something(*string);
```

Without the const, for clarity:

```
for (char **string = string_list; *string; string++)
    do_something(*string);
```

This is the same technique that is often used with strings themselves:

```
for (char *c = string; *c; c++)
    process_char(c);
```

You can also pass the list to a function without having to also pass the length.

It also makes it easy to refer to a subsequence of the array, provided it's at the end.